# Collection to typed array

Tags: java, arrays, generics, reflection, collections

If I have a `Collection` defined as `Collection collection = new ArrayList()` which contains `String` instances, how can I convert it to a `String[]`? `collection.toArray()` returns an `Object[]`. Alternatively, how can I instantiate an `ArrayList<String>` using reflection?

Note that I cannot hardcode `String`, the method doing this only knows about the `Class` that it can work with.

Example:

```
Object test(Class classToCastTo, Object[] values) {
    Collection collection = new ArrayList();
    for (Object value : values) {
        collection.add(classToCastTo.cast(value));
    }
    return collection.toArray();
}
```

If I call this with `test(String.class, ...)`, then it will return an `Object[]`. How can I make it return a `String[]`?

Comment: Any reason you're not using List<string> ?

Comment: @ChrisGessler, I cannot hardcode `String`, the method doing this only knows about the `Class` that it can work with.

Comment: Collection is an interface, How can you create an object of it?

Comment: @Owl, I'm not, I'm creating an `ArrayList` object.

Comment: If the type isn’t hardcoded, how does the code know that it needs a `String[]`? That implies static typing, which you don’t seem to use. You cannot even declare the array, much less create it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, added an example of what I mean.

Comment: Is using Guava's Iterables.toArray(Iterable, Class) out of the question?

Answer (score 4):

Use `theCollection.toArray((T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(theClass, theCollection.size()))`, where `T` is the element type. The cast is safe as long as `T` is an unparameterized type.

Comment: I think OP needs this without the `T[]` cast since he doesn’t have the type (otherwise he could just use a generic `Collection`. But otherwise this looks essentially right.

Comment: I would try and avoid reflection (if not strictly required), and casting arrays is not recommended either.

Comment: @owlstead, indeed, I don't use reflection lightly. But unfortunately it is required here.

Comment: @Radu OK, got it upvoted the answer. I thought you only could not cast your `Collection` to `Collection<String>` beforehand. Do you really need a parameterized method for this? You are better off performing the `toArray()` where you require the String array. Creating type unsafe helper methods is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the class, you can write a method like this:

```
public static <T> T[] arrayBuilder(Class<T> classToCastTo, Collection c) {
  return (T[]) c.toArray((T[]) Array.newInstance(classToCastTo, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you need:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] originalArray = {"abc", "def"};
    Class clazz = String.class;

    Object[] newArray = test(clazz, originalArray);
    System.out.println(newArray.getClass()); //class [Ljava.lang.String;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray)); //[abc, def]
}

static Object[] test(Class classToCastTo, Object[] values) {
    Object[] o = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(classToCastTo, values.length);
    System.arraycopy(values, 0, o, 0, values.length);
    return o;
}
```

You will get a `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` if the original array contains something that is not a `String`.

Comment: @Radu Sorry - I had not understood that part.

Comment: @Radu Does it work for you following the edit? (just noticed that Ben has come with something similar in the meantime)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the Collection and store it in a String array.

Try this example from my code:

```
Collection c = new ArrayList();
c.add("Vivek");
c.add("Vishal");
String[] arr = new String[ c.size()];
int j = 0;
for (Object s : c){

arr[j] = (String)s;
j++;
}
```

Comment: Again, I can't use the `String` symbol. I have a `Class` which is `String.class`.

Answer (score 0):

The following method is what are you looking for

```
public <T> T[] test(Class<T> classToCastTo, Object[] values) {
    Collection<T> collection = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Object value : values) {
        collection.add(classToCastTo.cast(value));
     }
    return collection.toArray((T[])Array.newInstance(classToCastTo, collection.size()));
}
```

Comment: Just call it like `test(String.class, myArray)` and it will return an array of `String`. In fact first parameter is your desired type and second parameter must be an array of objects which are castable to that type.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ben’s answer, the following code snippet works (compiles without warnings and runs):

```
private static Object test(Class<?> classToCastTo, Object[] values) {
    Collection<Object> collection = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (Object value : values) {
        collection.add(classToCastTo.cast(value));
    }

    return collection.toArray(
        (Object[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
            classToCastTo, collection.size())
    );
}
```

Now you can call the method via

```
String[] result = (String[]) test(String.class, someValues);
```

The trick is casting the array that was created via reflection to `Object[]` so that it satisfies the static type check and matches the parameter type required by `toArray`.

*That said*, I don’t understand why you can’t call the method with a generic parameter. If you don’t have a generic type *somewhere*, the result of this method will be useless anyway.

Comment: I'm mapping one object to another. One object is a `Map`, the other is an instance of a separate class. This class has many properties, each of different types. I also have a method that translates the `Map` to these types. The method does different things to obtain the correct representation of these types and returns an `Object` to be assigned. This `Object` needs to be correct.

Comment: @Radu Not sure I follow but this code should definitely work then. My example call obviously doesn’t make a lot of sense but it demonstrates that the array is of the correct type. Another remark, I would forego using arrays completely. They are an ugly remnant from the past. I pretty much exclusively use collection classes (Josh Bloch says much the same in *Effective Java*, IIRC).

Comment: I definitely have nothing against collection classes, but the object I'm mapping to will likely use arrays as well. This conversion to and from arrays though seems to be very sub-optimal to say the least.

Comment: @Radu I’m not sure what’s suboptimal here. The conversion doesn’t actually incur an action at runtime, it’s only there for the static type checker. And since you don’t know the type, you *need* to create the array via reflection. The rest of the call is actually the same that you’d normally use, i.e. the normal `toArray` call idiom.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your collection only contains Strings, this method

```
public static <T>  T[] toArray(Collection collection, Class<T> clazz) {
    T[] array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, collection.size());
    return ((Collection<T>) collection).toArray(array);
}
```

called as

```
String[] result = toArray(collection, String.class);
```

will do what you need, though it will give some warnings about unchecked casts.

If you know your collection can only contain strings though, you ought to be able to declare it as a `Collection<String>` and avoid this sort of mess.

Comment: The whole point is that the OP doesn’t have a generic type though. This answer is equivalent to Keppil’s answer.

Comment: I understand that.  My point is he'd be better off trying to have a generic collection in the first place.  This method casts a non-generic collection to a generic collection, and will certainly fail if the collection contains something it oughtn't.  But it does what he wants.

Comment: I hadn't noticed Keppil's answer.  Yes, it is equivalent.

Comment: If you're getting an ArrayStoreException, you almost certainly have something in the collection that doesn't match the type expected.  I get this error if I use a collection containing both `String` values and `Integer` values and pass `String.class` as the class parameter.